# how I get component element like link function elem variable in angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, ng-upgrade

I am new in angular 1.5 now I have a problem. How I get current component element reference in controller function like angular 1.3 **link : function(scope, elem, attr)** function. **elem** denote to directive element.

Angular 1.3

```
templateUrl : "template_url",
link : function(scope, elem, attr){
    elem.find(".chips-item").append("<h1>Angular 1.3</h1>");
}
```

Angular 1.5

```
templateUrl : "template_url",
controller: function() {
    elem.find(".chips-item").append("<h1>Angular 1.3</h1>"); /// How I get current Element
}
```

Comment: You can use `this` keyword.

Comment: No @StarkButtowski iss getting error **TypeError: vm.bind is not a function**

Answer (score -1):

Try to use link function to operate on DOM
and communicate with a controller via scope:

```
//assign something to scope
scope.property = value; 

//watch scope changes in link function

scope.$watch('property', function (newVal, oldVal) { 
    /*callback on      scope changes*/
  } );
```